# Export all columns to text files with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script to export each column to a .txt file, but for some reason it keeps getting stuck on the line "Open myFile For Output As #1". It's important that I can use both row 1 and 2 as headers, that I can use the strings in those rows to compile the filename, and that the values in the filename are separated with an underscore (makes it easier to import in R). Any ideas?

```
Sub export_data()
    Dim row, column, i, j As Integer
    Dim fullPath, myFile As String
    fullPath = "C:\Users\Test\Documents\R\1 Template - Test\tmp"
    row = 300
    column = 100
    For i = 1 To column
        myFile = "Template_test_" + Cells(1, i).Value + "_" + Cells(2, i).Value + ".txt"
        myFile = fullPath + "/" + myFile
        Open myFile For Output As #1
        For j = 1 To row
            Print #1, Cells(j, i).Value
        Next j
        Close #1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: you have to use "\" (backslash) to concatenate path and filename

Comment: Alternatively add the separator to end of `fullPath = "C:\Users\Test\Documents\R\1 Template - Test\tmp\"` and just use `myFile = fullPath & myFile`